# Can we mix In app purchase and Auto renew Subscription?

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, subscription, in-app-subscription, auto-renewing

We have an app and need following use case to be fulfilled is it possible on iOS and android stores ?

Sample :

1. User will Pay 10$ to Download the app.
2. Once Downloaded app will showcase all content for 1 year in this 10$
3. Now after 1 year We want to charge user an auto Subscription fees of 5$ every year.

Can we mix this methods where user pays for initial download and then also subscribe inside app ?

If this is possible please suggest methods to be used.

Also We plan to develop this app Using React Native.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have both IAP and paid model, we call it `Paymium` Business Model.
[Read about business models on Apple official website.](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/business-models/)